# How to rethrow error in shareReplay based http caching approach in angular?

Tags: angular, error-handling, rxjs, observable

I experimented a bit and built an easy http cache for entities which will never change but need to be used at the frontend.

The solution uses shareReplay

```
@Injectable()
export class BaseDocumentTypeService {

    private cacheAllTypes$: Observable<BaseDocumentType[]>;

    constructor(private typeService: TypeService) {
    }

    public getAllBaseDocumentTypeCached(tenantId: number): Observable<BaseDocumentType[]> {
        if (!this.cacheAllTypes$) {
            this.cacheAllTypes$ = this.typeService
                                      .getAllTypes(tenantId)
                                      .pipe(
                                          shareReplay(1)
                                      );
        }
        return this.cacheAllTypes$;
    }

}
```

In case of an error I just want to rethrow that error (same behaviour as HttpClient does). How to approach and rethrow that error?

Trivia: The call of baseDocumentTypeService is part of a forkJoin where many backend calls are consolidated.

Comment: So what's the problem with what you have now? It doesn't rethrow the error?

Comment: I want to have a short review if errors are rethrown

Comment: if you cache the error, i can't see there is any logic in the current code to re execute the service call.